# x11 code does not compile in Code Blocks

Tags: x11

I am currently running the latest version of Code-blocks in Ubuntu 11.04.
I have GTK+2, and 3 developer libraries fully installed (and working), and presumably have x11 installed. The header files are there.

However, a simple code will not compile using x11 coding.

```
#include "X11/Xlib.h"

int main() {
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay(0);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    XWarpPointer(display, None, root, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

This give me the readout of:

> obj/Release/main.o||In function `main':|
>
> undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
>
> undefined reference to `XWarpPointer'
>
> undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
>
> |=== Build finished: 3 errors, 0 warnings ===|

I've tried reading multiple webpages of 'linking' x11, I only find headerfiles, and not the file type asked by the linker within the compiler (That's the wrong term for that.. it's not a compiler.. it's something else.. I know. Apologies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what Code Blocks is, but for a normal compile/link process, you need to specify `-lX11` to link with libX11.so for the Xlib functions.

Comment: Thank you so much. I found where to put this in 'other linker settings' as written command line parameter, and worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks! I just had the same problem. To spell it out:

Settings > Compiler and Debugger > Linker settings > Other linker options > "-lX11"

For the record 'codelite' got it right all by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeBlocks you can just set in the project options libraries to link against, setting -lX11 in the compiler settings will make *every* program you compile with codeblocks link against X11.